# React context method inside a useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a context with the following method that dispatches an action:

```
const AuthContext = createContext();
...

const loadUser = () => {
  try {

    dispatch({ 
      type: types.USER_LOADED, 
      payload: { 
        user: 'some_data'
      }});

  } catch(err) {
    dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_ERROR });
  }
}
```

then goes to a reducer:

```
case types.USER_LOADED:
   return {
     ...state,
     user: action.payload.user,
   };
```

On a component I'm trying to call inside a useEffect method:

```
const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

useEffect(() => { 
 
  authContext.loadUser();

}, []);
```

Then I got react-hooks/exhaustive-deps:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'authContext'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I tried put to the authContext on my dependency array, but I got a infinite loop. The loadUser method works as expected, but is it possible to avoid to get this warning?

I have try with hooks too, but the same warning persists, but on this case the warning goes on the loadUser method, but everything work as expected:

```
const useAuth = () => {
    const {
        loadUser
    } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
    return {
        loadUser
    };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Then:

```
const { loadUser } = useAuth();
useEffect(() => { 
  loadUser(); 
}, []);
```

Comment: Does the correct behavior continue when you do `const { loadUser } = useAuth(); useEffect(() => { loadUser(); }, [loadUser]);`?

Comment: it starts a infinite loop

Comment: Can you provide the code where `loadUser` is passed to the `AuthContext.Provider`? That's very relevant here.

Comment: ```return (<AuthContext.Provider value={{loadUser}}> {props.children} </AuthContext.Provider>);```